# how to get manager's name from employ name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

How do I find manager name here. Each manager is also an employee.

```
EmpID  Name  ManagerId
  1     A       3
  2     B       1
  3     C       2
  4     D       5
  5     E       1
```

Expected result is like this

```
EmpID  Name  ManagerName
  1     A       C
  2     B       A
  3     C       B
  4     D       E
  5     E       A
```

Comment: @mm759 Every manager is also an employee, so the names are provided. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39241981/2422776) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can self join the table, and use the joined instance to get the manager's name:

```
SELECT e.empid, e.name, m.name
FROM   employee e
JOIN   employee m on e.managerid = m.empid
```

Comment: The `JOIN` line should be `JOIN   employee m on e.managerid = m.empid`. You have `e.` on both sides of the joined fields.

Comment: @Shiva arg, stupid typo. You are right, of course. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Left Join for the desired output..otherwise you will miss some employee who doesn't have managers ..

```
SELECT e.empid, e.name Employee, ISNULL(e1.name,'') Manager
FROM   employee e
LEFT JOIN   employee e1 on e.managerid = e1.empid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #MYTEMP
(
     EmpID  INT
    ,Name  VARCHAR(10)
    ,ManagerId INT
)

INSERT INTO #MYTEMP VALUES
(1,'A',3),( 2,'B',1),(3,'C',2),(4,'D',5),( 5,'E',1)

SELECT EMP.EmpID AS EMPNO,
       EMP.Name AS EMPLOYEE,
       MGR.Name AS MANAGER
FROM #MYTEMP EMP
JOIN #MYTEMP MGR
ON EMP.ManagerId = MGR.EmpID
```